# Can't connect to my SQL Server database, ERROR: I don't have permission to open the file?

Tags: sql-server

[image][image][image]

I keep getting this error

> You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner [ME] or an administrator [ME] to obtain permission.

I checked my computer and I am the administrator, I did properties on the actual database & looked at Security [see picture captured of my security to this database. I even changed the "Owner" to Administrator, was `MSSQLSSQLEXPRESS` and still get the error.

Changed the Security setting [Owner] of the Database to Administrator of which I am the Administrator.

I captured a copy of the actual error, see below.

Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Are you running whatever it is that gives you this error (I asume SSMS) with elevation? If not, you'll still have no permission to access it, as you'll just be an ordinary user.

Comment: what @JeroenMostert means is when you run it from windows you have to right click and select "run as administrator"

Comment: Yes, or hold Ctrl-Shift as you click the icon.

Comment: Jeroen,  I am running Microsoft Visual Studio [web development] and trying to make a connection to the Server Database and yes, I am running SSMS.  How would I check that?

Comment: SSMS should have "(Administrator)" in the title bar if it's elevated.

Comment: The error is coming from MS Visual Studio.  I just opened SSMS with right click & run as administrator and still get the error.  So would it not be that MS Visual Studio is the problem ?   I just opened up the "Add connection" window in MS Visual Studio & notice that the "Log on to server" is selected to "Use Windows Authentication".   I can select "Use SQL Server Authentication"  but it wants a User name & password.  How would find the username & password if this is the problem.

Comment: Jeroen, yes I see it now since opening with right click as advised.

Comment: The function in VS that you're using is intended to open database files in a user's own folder by attaching it to the database server on the fly. This is not what you want if the database is already available and attached to SQL Server. Use "Microsoft SQL Server" for the source, not "Microsoft SQL Server Database File", and use `.\SQLEXPRESS` for the server name. Trying to attach the file directly afterwards will fail because SQL Server takes exclusive control of it (so it wouldn't work even if you got around the permissions).

Comment: I just now noticed that the "Add Connection" window above and the "Data Source" had an option for "Microsoft SQL Server" [I had selected Microsoft SQL Server Database File"] and was giving the error.  So now that I selected "Microsoft SQL Server" it connected!      Thanks for all of your help, I probably wouldn't have noticed this and most likely the running of SSMS as Administrator made all the difference!